# Updating Labels to show the width and height of the scene in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, data-binding, properties

I'm trying to make a small JavaFX program that prints out the width and height of the current window, and updates it automatically using properties and bindings.

I tried a lot of things, and came to this solution:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Label width = new Label();
        Label height = new Label();
        TextField widthTf = new TextField();
        TextField heightTf = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Resize");
        root.getChildren().addAll(width, height, widthTf, heightTf, button);

        IntegerProperty widthInteger = new SimpleIntegerProperty(320);
        IntegerProperty heightInteger = new SimpleIntegerProperty(240);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, widthInteger.getValue(), heightInteger.getValue());

        width.textProperty().bind(widthInteger.asString());
        height.textProperty().bind(heightInteger.asString());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            widthInteger.setValue(Integer.parseInt(widthTf.getText()));
            heightInteger.setValue(Integer.parseInt(heightTf.getText()));
            stage.setWidth(widthInteger.getValue());
            stage.setHeight(heightInteger.getValue());
            widthTf.clear();
            heightTf.clear();
        });

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args);}
}
```

It is definitely not pleasing to the eyes, but that is not my main goal here, and even tho using the button does update the values and resize the window, it just feels like cheating to me. I'm pretty sure there has to be a better way than this, and if there is, I would like to know what exactly. I tried using `scene.getWidth()` and `scene.getHeight()`, but I couldn't solve it with them.
I might be just overthinking this, but it definitely feels like a cheating solution and like there is a better and cleaner way.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this will work properly if the user resizes the window in the usual way, by dragging the borders or corner. Isn't that what you want to support? Do you really need the text fields?

Comment: That would be the main goal yes, but as I was trying to make things happen I realized that I'm not even sure if I could just give it another values and that way it would work, and well it wasn't, so firstly I tried achieving that, which has happened, but I'm pretty sure there is a much better way. Therefore I hoped someone would help me out with this example, then I could use that as a reference to solve the original problem, that is to drag the borders. TextFields are only there because that is the only way I was able to do it, they are not part of the original plan. @James_D

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the text fields and button and just do `width.textProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty().asString());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is simply to have labels which display the width and height of the window, `Stage` exposes a `widthProperty()` and a `heightProperty()`. You can just bind directly to those:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Label width = new Label();
        Label height = new Label();
        root.getChildren().addAll(width, height);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);

        width.textProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty().asString());
        height.textProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty().asString());

        stage.setScene(scene);


        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args);}
}
```

If you want them as integers, you can provide a format string:

```
width.textProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty().asString("%.0f"));
```

etc.

Comment: Yes this is it, I was sure I was dumb, cause it surely isn't a complicated matter, but it never occured to me there is width- and heightProperty. I was fixated on getWidth and getHeight. Thanks.

Comment: @LastKnyte Pretty much every value in JavaFX library classes is represented as an "observable" value via the property classes.